# I want to traverse the keys and the list in the hash map with the corresponding key i want the value(list) to be printed

Tags: java

I want to traverse the keys and the list in the hash map
with the corresponding key.

Want the value(list) to be printed. Can anyone help?

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,List<String> >  hashmapobj = new HashMap<String,List<String>();
    List<String> listobj=new ArrayList<String>();
    listobj.add("yellow");
    listobj.add("green");
    listobj.add("orange");
    listobj.add("blue");

    hashmapobj.put("color", listobj);
    hashmapobj.put("light", listobj);

    }

}
```

Comment: So, you want to search something like `("color")` and then print the list stored in that value?

Comment: I just want it to print it like-- "key=color value=yellow green orange blue" and similar for the next key

Comment: You mean like; `hashmapobj.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> items: hashmapobj.entrySet()){
    System.out.print(items.getKey());
    List<String> list = items.getValue();
    for(String s : list){
        System.out.print(" " + s);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This will print your `key` and then all of the values stored in your `List<String>` on the same line. Each key:value gets its own line.

Comment: Worked like charm
Thank you Micheal

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> m: hashmapobj.entrySet())
        {
            String key = m.getKey();
            List<String> list = m.getValue();
            System.out.println("Key is: "+key);


            System.out.println("Value is: "+list);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : hashmapobj.entrySet()) {
     for (String val : entry.getValue()) {
           //do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: Can u pls write the complete logic ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    String key = (String) iterator.next();



    Iist value = (list)map.get(key);

    System.out.println("Key: "+ key+", Value: "+ value);

}
```

May be this will help you